# IncompleteAnnotationException when accessing an annotation in groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I defined an annotation as follows

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited
import java.lang.annotation.Retention
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy
import java.lang.annotation.Target

/**
* Annotation for any object that exposed a remote interface
*/
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Remote {
String label()
}
```

and i'm trying to use it this way

```
import com.yascie.annotation.Remote

@Remote("Bar")  
class Foo {
    String name
    String value
    static String code
}
```

I keep getting though an error saying that the annotation is missing element label

```
java.lang.annotation.IncompleteAnnotationException: Remote missing element label
```

Now when i tried to inspect the annotation object i can see that a label method is available trough a proxy but i can't access it. Any ideas ?

```
Remote annotation = objectClass.clazz.getAnnotation(Remote.class);
annotation.metaClass.methods.each {println it}

public final java.lang.String $Proxy14.label()
```

- ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. If you want to use the `@Remote("Bar")` syntax then you need to change the `label()` method to `value()` since that's the method name for the default property for annotations when the name isn't specified.

If you want it to be called `label()` though, specify it as `@Remote(label="Bar")`